# A real analysis question that is too long, refer to the body.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $I$ be an interval in $\mathbb{R}$, $f$: $I$$\rightarrow$$\mathbb{R}$ and c$\in$$I$. Suppose there exists constants $K$ and $L$ s.t.

$|f(x)-L|$ $\leq$ $K|x-c|$, $\forall$$x$$\in$$I$. Show that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$. This is taken from Bartle and Sherbert's Introduction to Real Analysis.

My proof goes like this;

Proof:

Let $(x_n)$ be an arbitrary sequence in $I$ such that $lim(x_n)=c$ and $x_n$$\neq$$c$, $\forall$$x$$\in$$I$. Note that $lim(|x_n-c|)=0$ and $x_n-c\neq0, \forall$$x\in$$I$.
So,
$|f(x_n)-L|$ $\leq$$K|x_n-c|$. Hence, $lim(f(x_n))=L$ by a theorem. Therefore by the Sequential Criterion,, $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$.
$\blacksquare$

My only problem is that I can conclude that  $lim(f(x_n))=L$ if $K>0$, but  I cannot justify it. Can someone help?

Comment: $K<0$ is impossible. $K\ge0$ and the proof works ok. However I am deeply suspicious of your “hence, $\lim f(x_n)=L$” since proving that from first principles is essentially the entire point of the exercise. To skip that part with a one-liner is to skip the exercise, imo

Comment: @FShrike Please elaborate on why you are suspicious on that one. Thank you.

Comment: I did ${}{}{}$. I am not suspicious about whether or not it's true - I know it's true - but I think *you* should elaborate on it. Because that is hiding the main idea of the exercise

Comment: @FShrike ok, I will edit it. I misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K<0$, $0\leq |f(x)-L|\leq K|x-c| < 0$ for any $x\neq c$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, we have $K\geq 0$.

But I do agree with [FShrike](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/815585/fshrike), why does your expression proves that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n) = L$? It is the same expression as given by the question for $x\in I$, so you could "do the same step" and just say $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x) = L$. That is why it feels like skipping the point of the exercise. I'd say you need to show more clearly that $|f(x)-L|$ gets arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: I already edited it, please review again. As I said, my problem is justifying that K>0 (which is the condition that must be met according to a theorem), but I can only prove that K is not less than 0, like you did. I cannot prove that K is not equal to 0.

Comment: I'm sorry. Suppose that $K = 0$. Then, for all $x\in I$, $0 \leq |f(x)-L| \leq 0$, so that $f$ is constant and equal to $L$. Therefore, the limit is also equal to $L$. Since $K\geq 0$ and the case $K = 0$  is above, you can assume that $K > 0$ and continue with your proof.

Comment: Thank you. Now I can rest this question hahaha